# XSL: Manipulating a node while applying its descendant templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I work with XML text editions, where text nodes often appear alongside element nodes. For instance, `<w>` word elements contain text nodes but may also contain further formatting, e.g. to signal abbreviations, which are contained in `<choice>` environments:

```
<s><w>Any</w> <w>sentence</w> <w>may</w> <w>contain</w> <w>an</w> <w><choice>
 <abbr>abbr<am>.</am></abbr>
 <expan>abbr<ex>eviation</ex></expan></choice></w>.</s>
```

The source manuscripts often use word spacing that differs from where we would conventionally place our spaces. This manuscript word spacing is preserved within `<w>` word element tags, so a case of odd spacing could be `<w>ele phant</w>`. My XSL stylesheet is applied using a parameter to signal whether the current operation wants to output manuscript spacing ("ele phant") or lexical word spacing ("elephant").

My question: how do I conditionally remove spacing from within `<w>` nodes and make sure all descendant templates are still applied?

To clarify, the following will not work:

`<xsl:strip-space>`: this function cannot be applied conditionally. I need to build in an if-clause to check whether the normalization parameter is active, but `strip-space` is only allowed at the document's top level.

`<xsl:value-of>` in an environment like the following:

```
<xsl:template match="w">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($display, 'normalized')">
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The issue with my syntax here is that templates written for descendants are ignored, so that, for instance, a `<choice>` environment like the one in the first code block above outputs both the abbreviation and its expansion rather than one or the other.

Finally, `xsl:apply-templates`, which ensures the recursion lacking from the example with `xsl:value-of`, does not allow syntax like `translate` in its `select` attribute value.

How can I remove all spacing from the content of `<w>` nodes if a condition like the one in the `xsl:value-of` example is met, but still have it apply the templates of any descendant nodes?

Using XSLT 2.0.

Comment: You can `match="w//text()"`, that is all text node descendants of `w` elements and then in that template can do the replace or translate.

Answer (score 3):

I am not very confident in transcribing original spacings with whitespace characters. If you want to document odd word or letter spacing, maybe you should think about a more explicit method. For example, there is [`<tei:space>`](http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/ref-space.html). The odd spacing of `<w>ele phant</w>` would then be transcribed as `<w>ele<space/>phant</w>`. Additionally, you can describe how wide the space actually is, with `@quantity` and `@unit`. Such an element is much easier and more reliable to process with XSL than a (whitespace) character.

If you want to stick with the whitespace method, which I still consider legitimate nonetheless, Martin Honnen already gave a valid and solid approach. To expand on that, I would combine it with `@mode`, instead of querying `$display`on each single node:

```
<xsl:template match="w//text()" mode="normalizeSpace">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,' ','')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and instead call it from your main template like that:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($display, 'normalized')">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="normalizeSpace"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This would give you a greater flexibility to define other post-processing routines, and probably a better performance as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! However, it's not yet clear to me how to set it up so as to solve my original problem. I have templates for things like whether to display the `<abbr>` and `<expan>` from the example sentence, as well as any `@rend`. As soon as I call `xsl:value-of`, whether in the main template or the `w//text()` template suggested by Martin and yourself, I don't see those templates processed anymore, so it's displaying **both** the abbreviation and the expansion (which is messy) and it's **not** implementing any `@rend` instructions. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can think of the following issues here: First, you said that you call `xsl:value of`, but maybe it should be `xsl:apply-templates` (to induce further processing). Secondly, some of those other templates you mentioned could possibly interfere and override `w//text()`. Do you use a path that matches `w` somewhere else?

Comment: Just in case: If this turns more complicated, due to other templates which were not involved in the original question, consider either to submit a new question, or to expand your question with all relevant code.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use `xsl:apply-templates`, but I don't know of a way to use it in combination with `translate`; that's what prompted the original question.

Comment: I think you should use `translate` and `xsl:value-of` only in the template that matches `w//text()`, and `xsl:apply-templates` in all other cases (when your xpath matches elements).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did, so perhaps I have an error in some other aspect of my code. I'll ponder this for a bit to see whether I can solve it or formulate a new question. Appreciate your help!